# Android Screenshot and Screencap Permissions

Tags: android, linux, permissions, screenshot, adb

I'm trying to take a screensshot over adb logged as root and I'm getting a "Permission Denied" error.

```
screenshot -i /sdcard/screen.png
error: writing file /sdcard/screen.png: Permission denied
```

But if I use **screencap** it works.

```
screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/screenshot/screenshot.c) `screenshot` sets UID to AID_SHELL (shell user) before writing the file:

```
/* switch to non-root user and group */
gid_t groups[] = { AID_LOG, AID_SDCARD_RW };
setgroups(sizeof(groups)/sizeof(groups[0]), groups);
setuid(AID_SHELL);

png = fopen(outfile, "w");
if (!png) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: writing file %s: %s\n",
            outfile, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just modify the property of directory '/sdcard'

```
 chmod 777 /sdcard
```

This works in my phone.